# MySQL: Select all Combinations where required number of Combination Items is owned

Tags: mysql

I have a table **artefact_combos**:

```
id  name                            points  study_time
3   Climate Priority Oven           13333   13333
```

and another **artefact_combo_items** specifying items, and the number of those items required to make the **artefact_combo**:

```
id      artefact_combo_id   thing_id    number
138     3                   809         2
139     3                   798         3
141     3                   583         1
```

Then a third table of **user_thing**:

```
SELECT *
FROM `user_thing`
WHERE (thing_id =809
OR thing_id =798
OR thing_id =583) WHERE user_id=4
LIMIT 0 , 30

id      user_id  thing_id 
3229    4        583        
17756   4        583
```

So in this case user 4 has >= the required number of item number 583, but none of the other required items, so I'd expect and empty result. If the result was:

```
id      user_id  thing_id 
3229    4        583        
156     4        583        
17756   4        789
17856   4        789
67756   4        789
122323  4        809
434     4        809
```

I'd like a result set like:

```
id  name                            points  study_time
3   Climate Priority Oven           13333   13333
```

I'm trying to construct a MySQL query that will derive a list of **artefact_combos** for which a particular  **user_id** has the required number of **artefact_combo_items** for the **artefact_combos**.

My most recent attempt of the last four hours has been:

```
SELECT foo.thing_id,
count(user_thing.id)
FROM
(SELECT
  a.name,
  c.id,
  c.artefact_combo_id,
  c.thing_id,
  c.number
FROM artefact_combo_items AS c
  INNER JOIN user_thing AS b ON b.id = c.thing_id
  INNER JOIN artefact_combos AS a ON a.id = c.artefact_combo_id

ORDER BY a.name DESC) AS foo, user_thing WHERE  user_thing.id = foo.thing_id
```

My apologies if this question is too specific or badly explained; I may have bitten off more than I'm ready to chew just yet. Any thought, hints or teaches would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You appear to have no PRIMARY KEY on the 3rd table, potentially making things inordinately difficult

Comment: your query doesn't match your schema. maybe you could use this site http://sqlfiddle.com/ to create a minimal example and tell us, what results you expect

Comment: @Strawberry thank you - I've tried to change the question to be more specific about what I'm actually facing.

Comment: @inna tichman thanks for the resource! I'll put together a fiddle.

Comment: Do you have a `user` table?

Answer (score 0):

I would query for combo-user not having missing items:

```
SELECT ac.*
     , u.id user_id
  FROM artefact_combos ac
  JOIN ( SELECT distinct user_id id 
           FROM user_thing
       ) u
  WHERE not exists( SELECT 1
                      FROM artefact_combo_items aci
                        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT user_id
                                         , thing_id
                                         , count(1) cnt
                                      FROM user_thing ut
                                      GROUP BY user_id
                                             , thing_id
                                  ) ui
                          ON ui.thing_id = aci.thing_id
                      WHERE aci.artefact_combo_id = ac.id
                        AND (   ui.user_id is null
                             OR (    ui.user_id = u.id
                                 and ui.cnt < aci.number 
                                )
                            ) 
                  )
```

Comment: Hi @Sal - thanks that's really great, seems to be getting what I need. It is slower than I hoped to run the query, but with 3000 combos, 8000 combo items and around 7000 user items per user I'm not sure what I expected! Thanks again for helping over this roadblock.